# Copy and paste from colum into a row to make a 3 column table format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data that is in 1 column with all the data  together i.e, date, comment and amount. so A1 is date, A2 is comment and A3 is amount, and the cycle goes on.

I wanted to transpose this into a table format so basically the data in A1 is cut and pasted into B1, A2 is cut and pasted into C1, A3 is cut and pasted into D1 and continues on ... A4->B2, A5->C2, A6->D2

I have recorded a macro and it was a long list. Is it possible to simplify this as it is a repeating action  ? The action just need to stop when it has copied the last data in column A.

kind regards,

```
Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A7").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A8").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A9").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

use macro recorder to see the vb codes

Comment: In B1 put the formula `=OFFSET($A$1,3*(ROW()-1)+COLUMN()-2,0)` Fill across to ColD then fill down until you have all the data from ColA.

Comment: This works perfectly, Thank you, although I was looking for a Visual basic code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2021 or Excel 365 with the `SEQUENCE` function and dynamic arrays, you can simply use the formula

```
=INDEX(DCA,SEQUENCE(ROWS(DCA)/3,3))
```

where `DCA` is either a named range or the name of the table of values in column A.

Enter the formula in some cell, and the results will spill into the columns and rows.

[image]

You can do it using VBA.

The code below assumes your data starts in `A2` with a column header in `A1` on `Sheet6` and that your output will start at `Sheet6!D1`

Change references as needed

```
Option Explicit
Sub column2rows()
    Dim rRes As Range, vSrc, vRes
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

ReDim vRes(0 To (UBound(vSrc, 1)) / 3, 1 To 3)
vRes(0, 1) = "Date"
vRes(0, 2) = "Comment"
vRes(0, 3) = "Amount"
I = 2
For K = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1) / 3
    For J = 1 To 3
        vRes(K, J) = vSrc(I, 1)
        I = I + 1
    Next J
Next K
        
Set rRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 4).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "output" 'may need to change if language <> English
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was using an older version of excel so I can't test this. I am waiting for an answer that will use Visual basic code.

Comment: Why VBA?  It is easily done with other formulas, or even Power Query which has been available since Excel 2010.

Comment: for some reason I don't see the "sequence" function when I tried it. I get the #NAME? error, this is what I typed: =INDEX(A1:A18,sequence(ROWS(A1:A18)/3,3))

Comment: @Leo As I wrote, it did not appear until Excel 2021.  In any event, I'll edit my answer to add a VBA method.  To use formulas in pre-2021, you need a different function to generate the sequence of numbers.  In any event, I will edit my answer to show a VBA solution.

Comment: Thank you very much  Ron, appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Ron, I am using MS visual basic for windows applications version 7.1  I am getting a      compile error: invalid inside procedure when I tried to run it. data starts from A2 and has a header and I am in "Sheet6" is there anything else I am missing? thanks.

Comment: @Leo Maybe a typo? What line does it stop at?

Comment: Hi Ron, it stopped at the first line. I used it as a macro. "Sub 'name of macro' ()

Comment: @Leo Since I can't see your code, it's hard to figure out your problem. Take a look at this [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-inside-procedure) and, hopefully, you can find your error. A not unusual cause is having a statement like `option explicit` inside the code rather than at the top of the module.  Otherwise, upload your workbook that demonstrates the problem (sensitive information removed), and I'll try to take a look at it. Clearly, it works here.

Comment: @Leo I quickly looked at your code. Please tell me what you did not understand about the issue with the location of `Option Explicit` as mentioned both by me in my comments and in the reference to which I referred you? That is the reason for the error you reported.

Comment: Hi Ron, apologies, I am still trying to learn VBA, I am not sure where the location of the option explicit should be, I thought I can just copy that code and make it a macro to do it. Would you please elaborate and enlighten me please.

Comment: @Leo In order to better learn this structural information (which you should know if you are going to be using VBA effectively), please read about the differences between **Procedures**, **Modules**, and **Projects**. Then you could either modify your **Module** in accordance with my comments and the reference; or place the **Procedure** I provided in a different **Module** in your **Project**.